# Coffeescript-Javascript correlation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, private, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to understand how private methods are created using coffeescript. Following is an example code

```
class builders
constructor: ->
    // private method
    call = =>
            @priv2Method()
    // privileged method
    privLedgeMethod: =>
            call()
    // privileged method 
    priv2Method: =>
            console.log("got it")
```

Following is the generated JS code.

```
(function() {
  var builders,
    __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

  builders = (function() {
    var call,
      _this = this;

    function builders() {
      this.priv2Method = __bind(this.priv2Method, this);
      this.privLedgeMethod = __bind(this.privLedgeMethod, this);
    }

    call = function() {
      return builders.priv2Method();
    };

    builders.prototype.privLedgeMethod = function() {
      return call();
    };

    builders.prototype.priv2Method = function() {
      return console.log("got it");
    };

    return builders;

  }).call(this);

}).call(this);
```

Note that I have used "fat arrow" for the function definition. There are couple of things that I didn't get from the code.

1. what's the use of _this variable
2. if you run this code as : (new builders()).privLedgeMethod() than inside the call method it doesn't find priv2Method method. Even though the builders object does show priv2Method as a property of it's prototype.

Hopefully someone could shed some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `call` function is not a private method, there is no such thing in JavaScript so there is no such thing in CoffeeScript.

A more accurate description of `call` would be:

> a function that is only visible inside the `builders` class.

Defining `call` with `=>` creates something the behaves like a private class method. Consider this:

```
class C
    p = => console.log(@)
    m: -> p()

c = new C
c.m()
```

If you look in the console you'll see that `@` inside `p` is the class `C` itself, you'll see something in the console that looks like a function but that's all a CoffeeScript class is. That's why you see the `var _this` in the JavaScript. When CoffeeScript sees `=>` and you're not defining a method, CoffeeScript uses the standard `var _this = this` trick to make sure the references come out right in the bound function.

Also note that your `call` is, more or less, a private *class* method so there is no `builders` instance and you can't call the instance method `priv2Method` without a `builders` instance.

Your `privLedgeMethod` method:

```
privLedgeMethod: =>
    call()
```

will work fine because `call` is a function (not a method), the function happens to be bound to the class but it is still just a function. Hence the lack of an `@` prefix when you `call()`. If `call` was a proper class method:

```
@call: -> ...
```

then you'd call it as a class method in the usual way:

```
@constructor.call()
```

Here's a simple demo that might clarify things: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tQv4E/